# I can hardly see whether I have voted on this meta site

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

This meta site features a grey-in-grey design. Unfortunately, I can hardly see whether I have already voted on a question or answer, the small difference in grey value is not sufficient.

On the Meta site for worldbuilding.se the votes are clearly visible (they are orange, a colour that would also fit this site's design).

Comment: Agree, also affects some links and not others (which are bright orange, thus aggravating the belief that the similarly colored area wouldn't be clickable). Example: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/i-can-hardly-see-whether-i-have-voted-on-this-meta-site

Comment: Hi, now that we've had the new SE-wide site design a while, is this fixed satisfactorily? (For me it's plenty clear, but I've long forgotten whether this was originally an issue for me or not)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601: Yes, it is clearly visible now.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica What changed? The votes are still showing up grey to me here.

Comment: It was the colour of the arrows above and below the vote count. This is still fixed, I checked it again. Some other things are grey, too, but still readable without problems (at least for me).